# Tikz how to extract spherical coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have `X` coordinate defined in Spherical coordinate system (the point is to be situated on the circle so it's easier):

```
\def\Sx{0} \def\Sy{0} \def\Sz{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Sρ{"sqrt((\Sx)^(2)+(\Sy)^(2)+(\Sz)^(2))"}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Sθ{ifthenelse(\Sx==0&&\Sy==0&&\Sz==0,0,"acos(\Sz/(sqrt((\Sx)^(2)+(\Sy)^(2)+(\Sz)^(2))))")}
\pgfmathsetmacro\SΦ{ifthenelse(\Sx==0&&\Sy==0,0,ifthenelse(\Sy<0,"-acos(\Sx/(sqrt((\Sx)^(2)+(\Sy)^(2))))","acos(\Sx/(sqrt((\Sx)^(2)+(\Sy)^(2))))"))}
\tdplotsetcoord{S}{\Sρ}{\Sθ}{\SΦ}
\coordinate (X) at ($(S)+(xyz spherical cs:radius=2,longitude=-40,latitude=0)$);
```

However `X` coordinate defined this way cannot be extracted into `x,y,z` components:

```
% calc library    
\newdimen\Xx \pgfextractx{\Xx}{\pgfpointanchor{X}{center}} % this doesn't work for me
```

How can be coordinate defined in Spherical coord. system and then extracted into `x,y,z` or `ρ,θ,Φ`? Thanks.

Comment: Once it is on the page, it is a 2D coordinate and there is no way to go back to 3D coordinates.

Comment: Cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176241/15925